# Contract functions. Is it possible to see contract exception detail?

Tags: contract-invocation

Etherscan shows the following warning after I executed a function of my own contract.

```
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]
```

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x010bb2aa5de9a775a508b4ba00a2f66294df8c044d20139e5728206e480aaa39

How can I debug it? Is it identify where the exception was thrown?